# ApolloClient's updateQuery wouldn't re-render component with new data

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo-client

I have a component that queries a GraphQL backend to return an author's name and bio, along with all posts published by the author in question. I'm trying to paginate the posts being returned here. My query is as follows:

```
query users($username: String!, $postLimit: Int!, $postStart: Int!) {
  users(limit: 1, where: { username: $username }) {
    _id
    firstName
    lastName
    bio
    posts(sort: "createdAt:DESC", limit: $postLimit, start: $postStart, where: {isPublished: true}) {
      title
    }
  }
  postsConnection(where: {isPublished: true}){
    groupBy{
      author{
        key
        connection{
          aggregate{
            count
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The component running this query is using [Apollo Client](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/angular/recipes/pagination/#using-fetchmore) thus:

```
// /components/blog/SingleAuthor.jsx
import withStyles from '@material-ui/core/styles/withStyles';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import React from 'react';

import Loading from './Loading';
import { useQuery } from '@apollo/react-hooks';
import { NetworkStatus } from 'apollo-client';
import gql from 'graphql-tag';
import getUserQuery from '../../apollo/schemas/getUserQuery.graphql';
import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid';
import Head from 'next/head'
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import CircularProgress from '@material-ui/core/CircularProgress';

const styles = (theme) => ({
  root: {},
});

export const GET_USER = gql`${getUserQuery}`;

export const getUserQueryVars = {
  postStart: 0,
  postLimit: 2,
};

const SingleAuthor = (props) => {
  const {
    classes,
    authorSlug,
  } = props;

  const {
    loading,
    error,
    data,
    fetchMore,
    networkStatus,
  } = useQuery(
    GET_USER,
    {
      // variables: {username: authorSlug},
      variables: {username: authorSlug, ...getUserQueryVars},
      // Setting this value to true will make the component rerender when
      // the "networkStatus" changes, so we'd know if it is fetching
      // more data
      notifyOnNetworkStatusChange: true,
    },
  );

  const loadingMorePosts = networkStatus === NetworkStatus.fetchMore;

  const loadMorePosts = () => {
    fetchMore({
      variables: {
        postStart: posts.length
      },
      updateQuery: (previousResult, { fetchMoreResult }) => {
        if (!fetchMoreResult) {
          return previousResult
        }
        // console.log('previousResult', previousResult);
        // console.log('fetchMoreResult', fetchMoreResult);
        let oldRes = {...previousResult};
        let newRes = {...fetchMoreResult};
        let oldPosts = oldRes.users[0].posts;
        let newPosts = newRes.users[0].posts;
        oldRes.users[0].posts = [...oldPosts, ...newPosts];
        // console.log('Final result', oldRes);

        return Object.assign({}, previousResult, {
          // Append the new posts results to the old one
          users: [...oldRes.users],
        })
      }
    })
  };

  if (error) return <div>There was an error!</div>;
  if (loading && !loadingMorePosts) return <Loading />;

  const { users, postsConnection } = data;
  const [user] = users;
  const {
    _id,
    firstName,
    lastName,
    bio,
    posts,
  } = user;

  const postCount = postsConnection.groupBy.author.find(({key}) => key === _id).connection.aggregate.count;
  const areMorePosts = posts.length < postCount;

  console.log('postCount', postCount);
  console.log('areMorePosts', areMorePosts);

  return (
    <>
      <Head>
        <title>{`${firstName} ${lastName}`}</title>
        <meta name="description" content={`Posts by ${firstName} ${lastName}`} key="postDescription" />
      </Head>
      <Grid item className={classes.root}>
        <h1>{firstName} {lastName}</h1>
        <p>{_id}</p>
        <p>{bio}</p>
        {posts.map((post) => {
          return (
            <h2>{post.title}</h2>
          );
        })}
        {areMorePosts && (
          <div className={classes.root}>
            {loadingMorePosts ? (
              <CircularProgress style={{opacity: 0.3}} />
            ) : (
              <Button color="primary" className={classes.root} onClick={loadMorePosts}>Show more</Button>
            )}
          </div>
        )}
      </Grid>
    </>
  );
};

SingleAuthor.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.shape({
    root: PropTypes.string,
  }).isRequired,
};

export default withStyles(styles)(SingleAuthor);
```

As you can see, I'm currently attempting to return only 2 posts at a time with a `load more` button. This button when clicked, fires a `loadMorePosts()` method that retrieves next 2 posts, and so on. While the method is processing, the button is replaced by at loading progress icon (`CircularProgress`).

However, this is not working. The method does retrieve new posts alright, but it's not triggering a re-render of the UI which results in the progress icon staying forever and the retrieved posts never showing up in the browser. How to fix this?

For reference, the repo is up at https://github.com/amitschandillia/proost/blob/master/web and the results can be seen live at https://www.schandillia.com/blog/authors/amitschandillia.

**P.S.**: The queries can be tested at the GraphQL endpoint: https://dev.schandillia.com/graphql.

Comment: I think you accidentally posted the query again instead of the component code.

Comment: My bad, just added the right code. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Did you solve this issue?